Is fallibilism circular?
According to the IEP,

Fallibilism is the epistemological thesis that no belief (theory, view, thesis, and so on) can ever be rationally supported or justified in a conclusive way

Doesn’t the idea of “conclusive” imply the existence of degrees of knowledge? If so, how would this be justified without circularly assuming fallibilism to be true?

That's why it's called a thesis?

@tkruse what does something being a thesis have to do with the position reasserting itself circularly?

Indeed in fallibilism every thesis including itself is not true while waiting to be falsified even for axiomatic systems or categories in math in its natural attitude, therefore the usual binary monotonic logic calculus is not fit here and you need something else to correct its apparent circularity...


Concerning fallibilism one has to be more precise: It refers to
general theories, i.e. theories which make general statements of the kind: For all ...
A specific thesis like "Now the sun shines
in my backyard" is not covered by fallibilism.

Of course one may take fallibilism itself as a hypothesis. Then they have
to try to refute fallibilism. I do not know that until now any
attempt has been successful.
On the other hand, fallibilism has been confirmed by several cases
in science. E.g., the expansion of the universe with decreasing
speed has been refuted some decades ago; currently the universe
expands with increasing speed.

I do not know how to measure the degree of truthfullnes of a general
theory and whether  it is even meaningful to speak of a true theory.
History showed that each general theory will be superseded or at
least improved.


Aside: I consider mathematics to be an exception from fallibilism, because correct mathematical statements can be proved.

Could the argument be made that we merely experience the illusion of mathematical proofs? I don't believe that to be the case personally, but it's conceivable that the experience of understanding a mathematical proof is in and of itself illusory; that the feeling that it "makes sense" is incepted into us by some malign force.

@ConnieMnemonic What you describe does not seem to be an argument but a speculation. How to check it?

Oh, there's no way to check it, in the same way there's no way to check solipsism. It's a total speculation. But I'm pointing out that there is potentially a reason to think fallibilism does apply to mathematics.

It's a proposition to be proved or one advanced without proof, which is either based on a circular or arbitrary claim after one or more steps (if it is to be proved) or immediately arbitrary (if it isn't). Just like everything else, including everything in this answer. See: Münchhausen trilemma.
Fallibilism (as linked) is the thesis that no thesis can ever be conclusively justified, so attempting to conclusively justify it would be pretty silly. The best a fallibilist can hope to do is to show that, given certain arbitrary assertions that we're especially fond of, fallibilism follows.

But note that it’s the claim that nothing can be conclusively justified, not just justified. Conclusive justification only makes sense with respect to degrees of justification. So I don’t see how this is not just skepticism plus the additional, unjustified, claim that justification exists in degrees

Fallibilism is the epistemological thesis that no belief (theory, view, thesis, and so on) can ever be rationally supported or justified in a conclusive way.
Therefore:
It also follows that if you conclusively justify falllibism, then it is not true.
